# Google web fonts down backup?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webfonts

I am wondering if there is a way to go okay, google web fonts is down use this as the font source instead? Something like how we do window.jquery check to see if google jquery cdn is down and serve an alternative file?

Comment: In other words, are you looking for how to host the font file locally and use that?

Comment: No if the Google Web Fonts CDN is down. My site which depends on what ever font family will be completely messed up. As the entire site and spacing/width/etc relies on that particular font. I want to prevent that by serving a local version.

Comment: .... so then yes, isn't that what i said above?

Comment: You could just host the Google font on your own site. Granted, the Google CDN is much less likely to go down than your web server, but that's irrelevant since your site has to be up for the font's availability to matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply specify a web font version installed on your own server as the second option, e.g.

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapisx.com/css?family=Cantarell' rel='stylesheet'>
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'cantarellregular';
    src: url('cantarell-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('cantarell-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('cantarell-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('cantarell-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('cantarell-regular-webfont.svg#cantarellregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
body { font-family: Cantarell, cantarellregular; }
</style>
```

You will need a different name for the font family in your server; in the example I have used the name produced by [FontSquirrel @font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).

This way, the browser will try to fetch the font file first from the Google site, and if this fails for some reason, it will fetch the font file from your server.

I wonder why you don’t simply use the font from your own server, if you are worried about Google site being down. (It would be rare to see it down; but the connection from user’s device to Google site might be broken, even though connection to your site is OK.)

Comment: I had a similar thought...but I wonder how long the page would be unstyled before the browser reverted to the next font in the list (e.g. would it wait for the Google-hosted font request to timeout)

Comment: Googles CDN is faster then hosting it locally if that makes any sense. I simply wanted a backup.

Comment: this isnt quite right, there must be a way to check Google URL and decide if it is down immidiately before changing the url to the local host, the solution above is missing the second link for the local font... as for google fonts going down, today is the second time in a week :/

Comment: As for why not host it anyway, the reason is simple, first off that's why we prefer CDN, second, Google runs few server side checks and generates a much friendlier version of the file, check it out, access the same url from different browsers

Comment: Just serving a font locally is simpler than trying to check whether Google is down (from the user’s perspective). If you expect your page to render OK in the first place, I don’t see why you would be worried about having fonts delivered from the same server. After all, you would then rely on the server on which you need to rely on anyway.

Comment: in a world about to be dominated by "cloud hosting" and pay-per-bandwidth-KBs, i think it becomes more and more important to want to rely on others to host your files... but i guess its a huge leap of faith (trust)

Answer (score 1):

You can list multiple font families and they would be displayed in that order. For example

```
font-family: 'Skranji', cursive, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
```

This will use the Google webfont Skranji, if that's not available it will bump it to Verdana, and so on.

Comment: No, if Skranji is not available, it will bump to `cursive`, a browser-defined font that is assumed to be of cursive (continuous writing) kind but can in reality be just anything (probably something odd).

Comment: Here is a link that may enlighten you how this works, Thanks :)
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-family-prop
My example works perfectly as intended.

Comment: The cited CSS spec says clearly that the font name list is used sequentially. The browser will thus use `cursive` if Skrjanji is not available.